# How can I chunk a PyTorch tensor into a specified bucket size with overlap?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Specifically, I have a tensor of shape: `torch.Size([1, 16])`

I want to bucket this into 7 buckets (of 4 each). Example:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]`

should become:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [3, 4, 5, 6],
 [5, 6, 7, 8],
 [7, 8, 9, 10],
 [9, 10, 11, 12],
 [11, 12, 13, 14],
 [13, 14, 15, 16],
]
```

How can I achieve this with PyTorch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an [`unfold`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.unfold):

```
t.unfold(0,4,2)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
        [ 7.,  8.,  9., 10.],
        [ 9., 10., 11., 12.],
        [11., 12., 13., 14.],
        [13., 14., 15., 16.]])
```

Comment: What are the `(0,4,2)`? I get the 4, but what about the others?

Comment: `0` is the dimension to unfold, `2` is the step/stride. Here you're sliding along dimension `0` with stride `2`.

Comment: @Shamoon see the updated question for the link to document.

Comment: It appears that `unfold` takes a 4D tensor now?

Comment: There are two versions of `unfold`, one from `torch.nn` (wrongly linked previously) which requires 4D tensor. The one in this answer is a method of `torch.tensor` class, which still works. The answer is updated with correct link.